# Is there a way of using PayPal sandbox when testing Neto checkout?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, neto

I need to test the paypal payment system under Neto ecommerce. I have setup paypal sandbox and it works fine when used directly. It appears that Neto  is hard wired to only connect to "paypal.com" whereas the sandbox needs "sandbox.paypal.com" - I am not at all keen test the Paypal payments live!!   Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Look in Advanced Configuration[image] and search for paypal and you'll see the settings you need to change.